# How to install and use MIB files?

Tags: snmp, mib

I've run `sudo download-mibs` and downloaded two additional MIB files ([INFORMANT-OS-MIB](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/Files/MIBS/operating_system/SMIv2/INFORMANT-OS.MIB.txt), [WTCS-MIB](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/files/MIBS/Advanced/SMIv2/WTCS.MIB.TXT)):

```
$ ls -lA /var/lib/mibs/site
total 456
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 460726 2012-05-22 16:52 INFORMANT-OS-MIB
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1088 2012-05-23 08:55 WTCS-MIB
```

And created a symlink in the standard MIB directory:

```
$ ls -lA /usr/share/mibs/site
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2012-05-23 08:58 /usr/share/mibs/site -> /var/lib/mibs/site
```

But it's not able to translate this OID:

```
$ snmptranslate -Of 1.3.6.1.4.1.9600.1.22.11.1.1.19
.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.9600.1.22.11.1.1.19
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `snmpconf` is not including your custom MIBs. You need to make `snmptranslate`, which uses `snmpconf` aware of them. You do something like this:

`snmptranslate -M+/usr/share/mibs/site -m+ALL -Of 1.3.6.1.4.1.9600.1.22.11.1.1.19`